# Include rownames as labels in plot

Tags: r, plot

I am exploring the traveling sales man problem in R with the package `TSP`, everything works well but my only problem is that the name of the cities in the plot does not appear.

Basically in the last line of code, I want to get the rownames as labels

Code:

```
library(TSP)
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(x = runif(20), y = runif(20), row.names = LETTERS[1:20])
## create a TSP
etsp <- ETSP(x)
etsp
## use some methods
n_of_cities(etsp)
labels(etsp)
## plot ETSP and solution
tour <- solve_TSP(etsp)
tour
plot(etsp, tour, tour_col = "red")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have the city names as labels in the chart you can use `geom_text` in the library ggplot. The trick is to prepare your data in the right way.

For the plot the data needs to be reordered by the route.

```
tdf <- as.data.frame(tour)
orderd.cities.tf <- as.data.frame(etsp[tdf$tour,]) 
#          x          y
# C 0.40897692 0.64050681
# L 0.45333416 0.90229905
# A 0.28757752 0.88953932
```

afterwards you can plot this data using

```
ggplot(ordered.cities.tf,
       aes(x=x,y=y,label=rownames(ordered.cities.tf)))+
    geom_polygon(fill=NA,color="red")+
    geom_point(shape=15,color="white",size=6)+geom_text()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the row names as labels in two steps.  First, change your call to `plot` to include the parameter `xaxt='n'`, which will tell plot not to render its default x labels.  The make a call to `axis()`, specifying the labels you want to use.

```
plot(etsp, tour, tour_col = "red", xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=etsp[1:20], labels=labels(etsp))
```

The trick with using `axis()` is that the `at` values are the x values in your plot, which are accessed from `etsp`, and the corresponding labels come from the `labels()` function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, but is it not possible for the points in the plot to have the name of row-names?

Comment: Just use `labels=LETTERS[1:20]` if you want to directly use the row names from the data frame.